# Is there a way to stop readr::read_tsv_chunked() after a certain number of chunks?

Tags: r, readr

I'm trying to use `read_tsv_chunked()` on a large .tsv file, and would like to stop after a certain number of chunks.

@jimhester has suggested a useful approach to be able to interactively view a given chunk with `browse()`: https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/848#issuecomment-388234659, but I'd like to write a function that 1) returns just the chunk of interest; and 2) stops reading the file after returning that chunk.

I've modified Jim's response to return the chunk so that I can use it with a `DataFrameCallback`, but can't figure out how to stop the read from within `read_tsv_chunked()`.

My approach so far:

```
get_problem_chunk <- function(num) {
  i <- 1
  function(x, pos) {
    if (i == num) {
      i <<- i + 1
      return(x)
    }
    i <<- i + 1
    message(pos) # to see that it's scanning the whole file
    return(NULL) # break() or error() cause errors
  }
}

write_tsv(mtcars, "mtcars.tsv")
read_tsv_chunked("mtcars.tsv", DataFrameCallback$new(get_problem_chunk(3)), chunk_size = 3)
```

As you can see, that returns the chunk I want, but doesn't stop reading 'till the callback isn't getting any more chunks:

```
> read_tsv_chunked("mtcars.tsv", DataFrameCallback$new(get_problem_chunk(3)), chunk_size = 3)
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  mpg = col_double(),
  cyl = col_integer(),
  disp = col_integer(),
  hp = col_integer(),
  drat = col_double(),
  wt = col_double(),
  qsec = col_double(),
  vs = col_integer(),
  am = col_integer(),
  gear = col_integer(),
  carb = col_integer()
)
1
4
<I WANT IT TO STOP HERE, BUT DON'T KNOW HOW>
10
13
16
19
22
25
28
31
# A tibble: 3 x 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  14.3     8   360   245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
2  24.4     4    NA    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
3  22.8     4    NA    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jimhester to the rescue again - https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/851#issuecomment-388929640

> You can do this by using the SideEffectCallback (which is the default
>   when passed a normal function) and returning the results using the <<-
>   operator. The SideEffectCallback stops reading when the callback
>   function returns FALSE. e.g.
>
> ```
> library(readr)
>
> get_problem_chunk <- function(num) {
>   i <- 1
>   function(x, pos) {
>     if (i == num) {
>       res <<- x
>       return(FALSE)
>     }
>     i <<- i + 1
>  }
> }
>
> write_tsv(mtcars, "mtcars.tsv")
> read_tsv_chunked("mtcars.tsv", get_problem_chunk(3), chunk_size = 2, col_types = cols())
> #> NULL
> res
> #> # A tibble: 2 x 11
> #>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
> #>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> #> 1  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
> #> 2  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `read_tsv_chunked()` function in the `readr` package doesn't provide a function to stop the reading, I thought, maybe using the more basic `read_tsv()` function which does provide possibilities for skipping and stopping after reading-in n rows:

```
require(readr)
write.table(mtcars, "mtcars.tsv", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)

read_tsv_chunk <- function(fpath, start.row, end.row, ...) {
  # Read read_tsv() but only from row n to m
  # For the column names, read one line:
  df.1 <- suppressWarnings(read_tsv(fpath, skip = 0, n_max = 1))
  # Then read again, from start.row to end.row, both included
  skip.row = start.row - 1
  df <- suppressWarnings((read_tsv(fpath, skip = skip.row, n_max = end.row - skip.row , ...))
  colnames(df) <- colnames(df.1)
  df
}
```

Now:

```
read_tsv_chunk("mtcars.tsv", 7, 9) 
# read "mtcars.tsv" from the 7th to the 9th column (both included)
```

Gives:

```
## Parsed with column specification:
## cols(
##   mpg = col_character(),
##   cyl = col_integer(),
##   disp = col_integer(),("mtcars.tsv", chunk_size=3, col_names = TRUE, skip = 6, g
##   hp = col_integer(),
##   drat = col_integer(),d("mtcars.tsv", chunk_size = 3, skip = 6, col_names = TRUE
##   wt = col_double(),
##   qsec = col_double(),
##   vs = col_double(),
##   am = col_integer(),
##   gear = col_integer(),
##   carb = col_integer()
## )
## Parsed with column specification:
## cols(
##   Valiant = col_character(),
##   `18.1` = col_double(),
##   `6` = col_integer(),
##   `225` = col_double(),
##   `105` = col_integer(),
##   `2.76` = col_double(),
##   `3.46` = col_double(),
##   `20.22` = col_double(),
##   `1` = col_integer(),
##   `0` = col_integer(),
##   `3` = col_integer(),
##   `1_1` = col_integer()
## )
## # A tibble: 3 x 12
##   mpg          cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  `NA`
##   <chr>      <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
## 1 Duster 360  14.3     8  360.   245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
## 2 Merc 240D   24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20.0     1     0     4     2
## 3 Merc 230    22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
```

It is not nice that the `Parsed with column specification appears twice, the second time with wrong column names ...

Actually, you could also do:

```
df <- read_tsv_chunked("mtcars.tsv", chunk_size = 3, skip = 6, col_names = TRUE, guess_max = 3)
df

## # A tibble: 3 x 12
##   mpg          cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  `NA`
##   <chr>      <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
## 1 Duster 360  14.3     8  360.   245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
## 2 Merc 240D   24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20.0     1     0     4     2
## 3 Merc 230    22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
```

But it is not better than the function I wrote ...
(e.g. recognizes the `df$disp` not correctly

If you'd use `read.table` a very basic R function to read tables (`read.csv` and `read.delim` and their variants are wrapper functions for `read.table`):
There would be a `nrow =` parameter to determine after how many read-in lines to stop to read the file. And there is `skip =` parameter to determine how many lines should be skipped at the beginning.

```
read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", 
    dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "#", nrow = 3, skip = 2 * 3)
```

returns what you want:

```
  X18.1 X6  X225 X105 X2.76 X3.46 X20.22 X1 X0 X3 X1.1
1  14.3  8 360.0  245  3.21  3.57  15.84  0  0  3    4
2  24.4  4 146.7   62  3.69  3.19  20.00  1  0  4    2
3  22.8  4 140.8   95  3.92  3.15  22.90  1  0  4    2
```

Comment: what is the reason why you use the `readr` package? What advantage gives it to you? And why there are NA's in your col `disp`?

Comment: I indicated I'm using `readr` by using the `readr` tag when I posted my question. I've now also edited my question to be more explicit.

The NAs arise from the way readr assigns column type - in this case, that column is of type `int` and the values are doubles - easy to fix in the function call.

I'm using `readr` because I've found it useful to use tidyverse functions instead of non-tidyverse alternatives for consistency within a package or function. You can learn more about readr here if you like: https://readr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: okay, understood ... but watching the documentation, I don't see a way for restriction. Thus I wrote a new function above.